# Encriptar en javascript y desencriptar en php

Tags: php, javascript

Tengo la siguiente duda sobre este código php:

```
<?php
class Encrypter {

    private static $Key = "dublin";

    public static function encrypt ($input) {
        $output = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5(Encrypter::$Key), $input, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5(Encrypter::$Key))));
        return $output;
    }

    public static function decrypt ($input) {
        $output = rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5(Encrypter::$Key), base64_decode($input), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5(Encrypter::$Key))), "\0");
        return $output;
    }

}

$texto = "Soy un ejemplo";

// Encriptamos el texto
$texto_encriptado = Encrypter::encrypt($texto);

// Desencriptamos el texto
$texto_original = Encrypter::decrypt($texto_encriptado);

echo $texto_original;
echo $texto_encriptado;
?>
```

El código funciona bien lo que pretendo es usar la misma función de encriptar en  **javascript** y desencriptar usando esta función en **php**
claro usando la misma **key** espero me entiendan.

Comment: Si un ladron sabe la forma de como cerrar tu casa, no crees que tambien entonces sabra como abrirla? Si encriptas la informacion del lado del cliente con la llave publica, aun atacante le sera facil desencriptarla.

Comment: No entiendo que tiene que ver con la duda que estoy platinando.

Comment: Si encriptas la informacion del lado del cliente estando la llave que desencripta tambien DEL LADO DEL CLIENTE, solo habria que aplicar ingenieria inversa para desencriptar la informacion. Nunca encriptes informacion del lado del cliente.

Comment: Este código es solo un ejemplo . y  lo que  quiero es pasarlo a javascript

Comment: Me imagino que lo que se refieren algunos es que no debes encriptar del lado del cliente porque este tendría acceso a las claves y métodos (algoritmos) usados para encriptar. Lo permitiria hacer facilmente ingeniería inversa. Si lo que quieres es proteger los datos que viajan en la red utiliza protocolos https. Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mírate el cifrado RSA, con este en PHP puedes crear una llave publica y privada del lado del servidor y lo mismo desde el cliente.

Hay un Git interesante https://github.com/travist/jsencrypt

Comment: gracias por el dato